# How to get the specflow scenarios in c# objects

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I want to read each feature file and create objects for each scenario. After reading the *.feature* file. I should get objects like below:

**Input**

```
@mytag  
Scenario: Add two numbers  
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator  
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator  
    When I press add  
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

**Expected Output**

`Scenarios` - Gives all the scenarios in feature file.
   `Scenario.Steps` - Gives all the Given when then of that scenarios.
   `Scenario.Examples` - Gives all the examples.
   `Scenarios.Tags` - All the tags

**Code**

```
var lines = File.ReadAllText(@"P:\Test.feature");
var scenarios = lines.Split(new string[] { "Scenario: "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var scenarioList = new List<Scenario>();
for (int i = 1; i < scenarios.Length; i++)
{
    var ind = scenarios[i].IndexOf("\n");

    var scenario = new Scenario();
    scenario.Name = scenarios[i].Substring(0, ind);
    var toInd=scenarios[i].IndexOf("@");
    if(toInd>1)
        scenario.Steps = scenarios[i].Substring(ind,toInd);
    else
        scenario.Steps = scenarios[i].Substring(ind);
    scenarioList.Add(scenario);
}
```

Comment: Going to need a lot more detail

Comment: Need more information. What code have you already tried?

Comment: I have updated the question. Now I'm reading the feature file using File.Read() but it is not easier to get all the attributes by parsing the text in the Scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gherkin Parser should do what you're expecting. You can get it at [Nuget gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/gherkin/)